# Openshift -- install depedencies via composer?

Tags: php, google-drive-api, openshift

I've created a project using openshift and php (i use fillezila for server transfers etc.. not git)

As part of my project i want to upload files to my google drive,
google API state that i should install the Google Client Library with composer.

I couldn't find a simple beginners guide on how to use the composer in openshift and what should i do with it. I am a complete beginner in php and composer use.

Bottom line i want a simple way to upload file to google drive without authentication every time. (for example PHPMailer let you send mail without authentication every time  my PHPMailer script sends email to gmail, my password and user name are part of the script).

If I must use [google drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php).

Please explain how to use composer on openshift for google drive to install the library using composer and upload a file to the drive.

Comment: What version of OpenShift are you using, version 2 or 3. If you are using OpenShift 3, then you should be able to simply drop a ``composer.json`` file in the top level directory of your source code repo. See: https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-php-container/tree/master/5.6

Comment: thanx for your comment and sorry for the delay..i managed to find an addon that does what i wanted,take the emails sent with the files and save them to drive. but i will keep in mind your suggestion for use in the future, so thanx again!